# Не равны prefab объекта и объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть `prefab` (являющийся `trigger`'ом), передающийся в скрипт через public переменную:

```
public GameObject RedSphere;
```

[image: В инспекторе]

В скрипте создается объект с его помощью:

```
Instantiate(RedSphere);
```

Объект spawn'ится, но при сравнении (в функции `OnTriggerEnter`, когда тело с прикрепленным скриптом касается объекта) условие не выполняется:

```
other.gameObject == RedSphere
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Всё верно. Приведу аналогию. У Вас есть электронная книга (RedSphere). Вы распечатываете ее (Instantiate(RedSphere)), и у Вас на руках оказывается ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР этой книги. Электронная книга и напечатанная книга не равны. меняя что-то в напечатанной, в электронной книге ничего не поменяется. Но можно сравнить их, например, по типу книги (класс, компонент в префабе) или названию (Tag)

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, аналогия не удачная. Вторая распечатанный экземпляр не будет равен первому распечатанному экземпляру.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сравнивать так базовые типы:

```
int A = 3;
int B = 3;
bool AB = A == B; // true
```

Тоже самое с структурами(`struct`):

```
Vector2 A = new Vector2(1, 2);
Vector2 B = new Vector2(1, 2);
bool AB = A == B; // true
```

С объектами это не так:

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 3 }; // массив это объект
int[] B = { 1, 2, 3 };
bool AB = A == B; // false
```

При передачи объектов в значение полей/переменных или как аргументы, передаётся только ссылка на объект, а не значения как с базовыми типами и структурами. При сравнении объектов сравниваются именно их ссылки и это является проверкой, является ли объект тем самым.

Вы можете присвоить префабу уникальный `Tag` или `Layer` и сравнивать по ним:

```
other.gameObject.tag == RedSphere.tag;
other.gameObject.layer == RedSphere.layer;
```

Либо повесить на них какой нибудь скрипт для сравнения объектов по нему:

```
public enum ObjectColor { Red, Green, Blue }
public enum ObjectShape { Sphere, Cube }

public class ColorShape : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjectColor Color;
    public ObjectShape Shape;
}
```

---

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private ColorShape _redSphereTemplate;

    public void SpawnRedSphere ()
    {
        Instantiate(_redSphereTemplate.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent(out ColorShape colorShape))
        {
            bool Same = SameColorShape(colorShape, _redSphereTemplate);
        }
    }
    
    private bool SameColorShape (ColorShape csA, ColorShape csB)
    {
        return csA.Color == csB.Color && csA.Shape == csB.Shape;
    }
}
```